# Bigquery InsertAll not working as expected

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the following code to insert logs from FILENAME. The log file contains 1000s of lines. With new lines being added ever few seconds. However when I run this code, the resulting table has only 15-20 odd rows.

```
      Rows dfpadunit = new TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows();
      List<Rows> dfpadunits = new ArrayList<Rows>();

      TableDataInsertAllRequest content = new TableDataInsertAllRequest();
      content.setIgnoreUnknownValues(true);
      content.setSkipInvalidRows(true);

      reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( FILENAME ) );

      while( running ) {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          TableRow aRow = new TableRow();
          aRow.set("RAW_DATA", line);
          String time = BigqueryUtils.getCurrentYYMMDDHHMM();
          aRow.set("TIME", time);

          dfpadunit.setJson(aRow);
          dfpadunit.setInsertId(time);
          dfpadunits.add(dfpadunit);
        }
        if(dfpadunits.size() > 0) {
          content.setRows(dfpadunits);

          TableDataInsertAllResponse response = BQUtils.run(PRE_STG_DATA_SET_ID, DESTINATION_TABLE, content);
          dfpadunits.clear();
          if(response != null) {
            formatTable();
          }
        }
        System.out.println("About to sleep");
        Thread.sleep( 1000 * 60);
      }
```

Comment: how are checking the size of the table in BigQuery?

Comment: A simple select count(*). I tried this a day later too and it was still the same.

Comment: The insert is used as the deduplication key. You are using the current time in minutes as the insert id. This means that all inserts during the same minute use the same dedup key -- only the last one survives. You will want to either leave the insert id empty or use a randomly generated ID as the insert id

Comment: @PavanEdara that fixed it. If you add your reply as an answer, I'll mark this as fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insert id is used as the deduplication key. You are using the current time in minutes as the insert id. This means that all inserts during the same minute use the same deduplication​ key, and thus only the last one survives. You will want to either leave the insert id empty or use a randomly generated ID as the insert id.